# How to pad hexadecimal numbers with 4 zeros in awk?

Tags: awk

INPUT

```
    63 0063 
    63 0384 
    0 0065 
    65 0065 
    6A 0065
```

OUTPUT

```
    0063 0063 
    0063 0384 
    0000 0065 
    0065 0065 
    006A 0065
```

Using awk '{printf "%04s %04s\n",$1,$2}' outputs spaces instead of zeros

```
 63 0063 
  63 0384 
   0 0065 
  65 0065 
  6A 0065
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the hex to a number and then print it as hex again:

```
awk '{printf "%04x", strtonum("0x"$1)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Why not use sed to convert spaces to 0s?

I think this could work:

```
echo 63 | awk '{ printf "%4s\n", $0 }' | sed 's/ /0/g' 0063
echo DF | awk '{ printf "%4s\n", $0 }' | sed 's/ /0/g' 00DF
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `%s` in awk's printf. You can use this command:

```
awk '{printf "%06s %06s\n", $1, $2}' file.txt
```

to get width of 6 where spaces will be padded with zeros before.

**To do same thing in pure bash use this code:**

```
while read a1 a2
do
   printf "%06s %06s\n" $a1 $a2
done < file.txt
```

Comment: I removed the extra %s.awk '{printf "%04s %04s\n",$1,$2}'
The output still gives spaces instead of zeros.

Comment: That is very strange. May I know what is your working environment? I mean what BASH and awk version are you running?

Comment: Every version of Bash that I tried, plus zsh, ksh and dash all pad with spaces. Also mawk pads with spaces. For me, only gawk padded `%04s` with zeros. However, I also tried Perl and PHP and they both pad with zeros. Ruby pads with spaces. Python uses a somewhat different syntax and it pads with spaces.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I have `GNU Awk 3.1.3` that is padding zeroes even awk on my Mac `awk version 20070501` is also padding zeroes. Even my bash solution is padding zeroes on my Mac which is `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`

Comment: Also, `/usr/bin/printf` complains that the leading zero is an invalid conversion specification. My system is Linux. I tested on Bash 2.05b, 3.2.51, 4.0 and 4.2. I'm assuming that the difference is due to the implementation of `printf(3)` being different between OS X and Linux.

Comment: gawk in Ubuntu (GNU Awk 3.1.8) is too dumb and broken: `$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%030d\n", "12345678901234567890")}'
000000000012345678901234567168`
`$ awk 'BEGIN{printf("%030s\n", "12345678901234567890")}'
          12345678901234567890`

Comment: @Ark-kun: You can try pure bash solution as I suggested above.

Comment: It pads with spaces too =((. I'm so mad at Linux and my being unable to overcome it gracefully. Everything works in FreeBSD, but in Linux all GNU utilities are broken - awk, sort, etc.

Comment: `$ echo "1 2" | while read a1 a2; do    printf "%06s %06s\n" $a1 $a2; done
     1      2` The distro is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What's worse is that using `%030d` instead of `%030s` corrupts the string: `#FreeBSD`
`$ printf %030s 12345678901234567890`
`000000000012345678901234567890`

`#Linux`
`$ printf %030s 12345678901234567890`
`          12345678901234567890`
`$ printf %030d 12345678901234567890`
`-bash: printf: warning: 12345678901234567890: Numerical result out of range`
`000000000009223372036854775807`

Answer (score 0):

Using a substring technique will provide consistent results across various languages, although the syntax will vary. In AWK:

```
awk 'function pad(string) {return substr("0000" string, length(string) + 1)} {print pad($1), pad($2)}'
```

One way you could pass the length as an argument:

```
awk 'function pad(string, len,      z) {z = "000000000000"; return substr(substr(z, length(z) - len) string, length(string) + 1)} {print pad($1, 4), pad($2, 4)}'
```